# sql: select with count return null

Tags: sql, count

i have this sql:

```
SELECT `profile`.`nickname`, 
       `profile`.`gender`, 
       `users`.`email`, 
       Count(`photos`.`id`) AS `q` 
FROM   `profile` 
       INNER JOIN `users` 
               ON `profile`.`uid` = `users`.`id` 
       INNER JOIN `photos` 
               ON `photos`.`uid` = `users`.`id` 
WHERE  `users`.`id` = '405'
```

if count return zero, gender and nickname return null !! while gender and nickname is not null.
is there any problem with my sql code?

Comment: Can you rephrase that first line. I find it hard to understand

Comment: that doesn't give you an error? You should have a group by statement, to make that work

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a GROUP BY clause after the WHERE clause as you are aggregating profile`.`nickname`,` 
profile`.`gender`,` 
users`.`email` by the number of photos

```
GROUP BY `profile`.`nickname`, 
   `profile`.`gender`, 
   `users`.`email`
```